# trying to break out of for loop but keeps going back into it and performing recursive call

Tags: java, break, return

I just discovered the project euler website, I have done challenges 1 and 2 and have just started [number 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) in java... here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IntegerFactorise {

    private static int value = 13195;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> primeFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static int maxPrime = 0;

    /**
     * Check whether a give number is prime or not
     * return boolean
     */
    public static boolean isPrimeNumber(double num) {
        for(int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
            if(num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /*Multiply all of the prime factors in the list of prime factors*/
    public static int multiplyPrimeFactors() {
        int ans = 1;
        for(Integer i : primeFactors) {
            ans *= i;
        }

        return ans;
    }

    /*Find the maximum prime number in the list of prime numbers*/
    public static void findMaxPrime() {
        int max = 0;
        for(Integer i : primeFactors) {
            if(i > max) {
                max = i;
            }
        }

        maxPrime = max;;
    }

    /**
     * Find all of the prime factors for a number given the first
     * prime factor
     */
    public static boolean findPrimeFactors(int num) {
        for(int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
            if(isPrimeNumber(i) && num % i == 0 && i == num) {
                //could not possibly go further
                primeFactors.add(num);
                break;
            }
            else if(isPrimeNumber(i) && num % i == 0) {
                primeFactors.add(i);
                findPrimeFactors(num / i);
            }
        }

        int sumOfPrimes = multiplyPrimeFactors();
        if(sumOfPrimes == value) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }   
    }

    /*start here*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean found = false;
        for(int i = 2; i < value; i++) {
            if(isPrimeNumber(i) && value % i == 0) {
                primeFactors.add(i);
                found = findPrimeFactors(value / i);
                if(found == true) {
                    findMaxPrime();
                    System.out.println(maxPrime);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am not using the large number they ask me to use yet, I am testing my code with some smaller numbers, with 13195 (their example) i get down to 29 in this bit of my code:

```
else if(isPrimeNumber(i) && num % i == 0) {
                    primeFactors.add(i);
                    findPrimeFactors(num / i);
                }
            }

            int sumOfPrimes = multiplyPrimeFactors();
            if(sumOfPrimes == value) {
                return true;
            }
```

It gets to the break statement then finally the check and then the return statement.
I am expecting the program to go back to the main method after my return statement, but it jumps up to:

```
findPrimeFactors(num / i);
```

and tries to finish the iteration...I guess my understanding is a flawed here, could someone explain to me why it is behaving like this? I can't wait to finish it of :) I'll find a more efficient way of doing it after I know I can get this inefficient one working.

Comment: @BoristheSpider as in after return true, it does't return back to public static void main method...it goes back into the loop, I thought break would exit the loop and not go back in.

Comment: Your code is a little convoluted - I finally worked that out. I would note that `if(x == true)` is a horrible antipattern, `if(x)` is the correct syntax. Similarly with your `return` - just return the boolean value directly.

Comment: @BoristheSpider good spot :) thank you, what do you mean by similarly with my return?

Comment: @user2405469 Where the code causes a problem : `else if(isPrimeNumber(i) && num % i == 0) {
                    primeFactors.add(i);
                    findPrimeFactors(num / i);` try to add `return` like this: `else if(isPrimeNumber(i) && num % i == 0) {
                    primeFactors.add(i);
                    return findPrimeFactors(num / i);`

Comment: @Leron wow! please explain why that worked, or any links on why it behaved the way it did, apparently my understanding of the language is flawed, I have used java for a while, but this for some reason is perplexing

Comment: @user2405469 The most important here is to understand that the problem is caused from wrongly used recursion. This is not a language dependent. Every C-based language (like Java) has something called `Call Stack`. In order to understand why you got this problem I think the best place to start is understanding the `Call Stack`, how it works and so on...

Comment: Try also 125, 128, 52100 as test cases for the algorithm. Search for the number in the task to find more discussions of effective and efficient algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using recursion, which means that a function will call itself.

So, if we trace what your function calls are when you call `return`, we will have something like that:

```
IntegerFactorise.main()
|-> IntegerFactorise.findPrimeFactors(2639)
    |-> IntegerFactorise.findPrimeFactors(377)
        |-> IntegerFactorise.findPrimeFactors(29) -> return true;
```

So, when you return in the last `findPrimeFactors()`, you will only return from this call, not from all the stack of calls, and the execution of the previous `findPrimeFactors()` will continue just after the point where you called `findPrimeFactors()`.

If you want to return from all the stack of calls, you have to modify your code to do something like that:

```
        else if(isPrimeNumber(i) && num % i == 0) {
            primeFactors.add(i);
            return findPrimeFactors(num / i);
        }
```

So that when the last `findPrimeFactors()` returns, all the previous `findPrimeFactors()` which called it will return too.

Comment: @FlorenBayle thank you for this explanation, it is really clear to me now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are ignoring the return value from your recursive call to `findPrimeFactors()`.

Let's walk through this. We start with the initial call to `findPrimeFactors` that happens in `main`. We then enter the for loop as it's the first thing in that method. Now let's say at some point we get into the else statement and thus recursively call `frindPrimeFactors(num / i)`. This will suspend the looping, but as this recursive call starts to run you enter the for loop again (remember, the previous loop is merely paused and not finished looping yet). This time around you encounter the break, which allows this recursive call to finish out, returning true of false. When that happens you are now back to the original loop. At this point the original loop continues even if the recursive call returned true. So, you might try something like this:

```
if (findPrimeFactors(num / i))
    return true;
```

I'm assuming that you need to continue looping if the recursive call returned false. If you should always finish looping upon return (whether true or false) then try this:

```
return findPrimeFactors(num / i);
```